# How can I achieve below in nodejs? Need to display output of function in JSON format

Tags: json, node.js

I have created a variable, which I have used to calculate the output of a Linux command (gets the number of users). Later I would like to pass that as input with JSON format.

But everytime, it prints `0` instead of the number of users. I tried to look at many posts related to callback, but couldn't relate with the situation. Please help.

```
var child;
var count = 0;

child = exec('users | wc -w', function (error, stdout, stderr) { 
    console.log(stdout); count = stdout});
    exercise_1_Message = { numberUsers: count };
    res.json(test_1_Message);
});
```

Comment: Move "exercise_1_Message = { numberUsers: count }; res.json( test_1_Message);" right after " count = stdout;".

Answer (score 0):

Place `exercise_1_Message = { numberUsers: count };res.json(test_1_Message);` inside the callback function :

```
var child;
let exercise_1_Message;

child = exec('users | wc -w', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    exercise_1_Message = { numberUsers: stdout.match(/\d+/g)[0] };
    console.log(exercise_1_Message);
    res.json(test_1_Message)
});
```